# Ambiguous Entity in stanfors NER

Tags: python-3.x, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working on Stanford NER, My question is regarding ambiguous entities.
For example, I have 2 sentences:

> 1. I love oranges.
> 2. Orange is my dress code for tomorrow.

How can i train these 2 sentences to give out,

> first orange as Fruit,  second orange as Color.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrape data from sites like wikipedia,etc. and create a scoring model and then use it for context prediction.